# The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the list type 'TableRow

Tags: flutter

This is how my shared preferences file looks like

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_name">aaa</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_score">4</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_email">digrev@gmail.com</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_password">123</string>
</map>
```

I have a table, and I'm trying to display data in the form of name, email, and score in the table. However, I've been struggling for hours and can't seem to get it to work. It's giving me this error:

> The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the list type
> 'TableRow.

How can I fix this error? Thank you in advance.

```
Table(
            border: TableBorder.all(),
            children: [
              TableRow(
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(child: Text('Name')),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(child: Text('Email')),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(child: Text('Score')),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              for (var entry in userData.entries) ...[
    String key = entry.key;
    String deger = entry.value;
    if (key.startsWith('flutter.User_')) {
    String isim = key.substring(12); // 12 karakteri keserek ismi alır
    print('İsim: $isim, Değer: $deger');
    }

                TableRow(
                  children: [
                    TableCell(
                      child: Center(child: Text(entry.key)), // Key değeri
                    ),
                    TableCell(
                      child: Center(child: Text(entry.deger)), // Value değeri (Email)
                    ),
                    TableCell(
                      child: Center(child: Text('')), // Score sütunu boş bırakıldı
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `for` [control-flow operator](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators) which should not contain [statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)).

If you want to have some statemets before adding the `TableRow` into the list, you can use the `map` method:

```dart
Table(
  border: TableBorder.all(),
  children: [
    TableRow(
      children: [
        TableCell(
          child: Center(child: Text('Name')),
        ),
        TableCell(
          child: Center(child: Text('Email')),
        ),
        TableCell(
          child: Center(child: Text('Score')),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ...userData.entries.map((entry) {
      String key = entry.key;
      String deger = entry.value;
      if (key.startsWith('flutter.User_')) {
        String isim = key.substring(12); // 12 karakteri keserek ismi alır
        print('İsim: $isim, Değer: $deger');
      }
      
      return TableRow(
        children: [
          TableCell(
            child: Center(child: Text(entry.key)), // Key değeri
          ),
          TableCell(
            child: Center(
                child: Text(entry.deger)), // Value değeri (Email)
          ),
          TableCell(
            child:
                Center(child: Text('')), // Score sütunu boş bırakıldı
          ),
        ],
      );
    }),
  ],
),
```